# rails pg_search search in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I Have 3 models

```
class Site
  has_many :album_stats
end

class Album
  has_many :album_stats
end

class AlbumStat
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :site
end
```

Before Pg_search i searched like this

```
site = Site.first
site.album_stats.left_joins(:album).where('albums.tag LIKE ? or albums.title LIKE ?', "%#{@tag}%", "%#{@tag}%")
```

Now i am add pg_search gem and modify `Album` class

```
class Album
  include PgSearch::Model
  pg_search_scope :search,
              against: %i[title tag],
              using: { tsearch: { dictionary: 'english', tsvector_column: 'searchable', any_word: true } }
```

Search in album model works fine, but how can i modify my old query, to search through pg_search?

```
site.album_stats.left_joins(:album).where('albums.tag LIKE ? or albums.title LIKE ?', "%#{@tag}%", "%#{@tag}%")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this:

```
# app/models/album_set.rb

class AlbumStat
  include PgSearch::Model

  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :site

  pg_search_scope :album_search,
                  associated_against: { album: [:tag, :title] },
                  using: { 
                    tsearch: { 
                      dictionary: 'english', 
                      tsvector_column: 'searchable', 
                      any_word: true 
                    } 
                  }
end
```

Now, you can modify your query like this:

```
site.album_stats.album_search("Your Value")
```

Comment: Good, but PG find column `searchable` in table AlbumStat.

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column album_stats.searchable does not exist`